# Lodash get key values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an `array` of `objects`,

```
var out = [{
    "type": "1",
    "from": "13052033555",
    "to": "4444444",
    "amount": "40000",
    "date": 1461575799,
    "status": "1"
  }, {
    "type": "2",
    "from": "13052033555",
    "to": "1111111",
    "amount": "30000",
    "date": 1461575884,
    "status": "1"
  }...
];
```

I get only it's values without `keys`

Now i used this function to get the values from array like this,
I pass array then it returns only values without keys

```
function foo(a) {
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var obj = a[i];
    var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
      return obj[k]
    });
    values.push("[" + arr + "],");
  }
  return values.join('');
}
```

Then it returns the values data without keys like this,

```
[ ["1","13052033555","4444444","40000",1461575799,"1"],
  ["2","13052033555","1111111","30000",1461575884,"1"],
    ....]
```

**Question: How can i change my foo function to lodash?**

Comment: `out.map(obj => _.values(obj))`

Comment: Other solution `out.map((e)=>Object.keys(e).map((key)=>e[key]))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [_.values()](https://lodash.com/docs#values)

```js
    var out = [{
        "type": "1",
        "from": "13052033555",
        "to": "4444444",
        "amount": "40000",
        "date": 1461575799,
        "status": "1"
      }, {
        "type": "2",
        "from": "13052033555",
        "to": "1111111",
        "amount": "30000",
        "date": 1461575884,
        "status": "1"
      }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
      out[i] = _.values(out[i]);
    }
    

console.log(out)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

`out.map(_.values);`

Or if below ES5: `_.map(out, _.values);`