# Get only values from array (without key)

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've have the function:

```
function getCotas() {
  var values = [];
  values['first'] = 10;
  $('.loop.scota').each(function(key, value) {
    var id = key + 1;
    values[$('.sdate.id' + id).text()] = parseInt($(this).text());
  });

  return values;
}
```

The output is the array with the keys:

`[first: 160, 01/12/2017: 157, 04/12/2017: 153]`

What I need is just the values of the array, without the keys:

`[160,157,153]`

I already tried to do a loop with the values, [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284125/lodash-get-key-values-from-array-of-objects), but always return an empty [] or an error with the functions.

Someone knows how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below example code:

```
var values = [];
    values["key1"] = "value";
    values["key2"] = "value";
var result = [];
for (var key in values) {
    result = result.concat(values[key]);
}

alert(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afje1Lhb/

Comment: Eh? Javascript has no `=>` operator for arrays (as I know) and you don't answer for question, the main point is how to put these values into array.

Answer (score 1):

Array push should be what you're looking for.

```
values.push(parseInt($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the loop if the keys are not important:

```
function getCotas() {
  var values = [];
  values[0] = 10; // first value
  var elArr = $('.loop.scota').toArray();
  values = values.concat(elArr.map(function (el) { return parseInt( $(el).text()); }));

  return values;
}

console.info(getCotas());
```